# Detect if a fixed positioned div is scrolling over specific divs

Tags: javascript, scroll, css-position

Is it possible to detect if div is hovered by another one in `position:fixed`?
My case is this one: I have a header with two links in a fixed position. When scrolling, I would like to detect if this or that other div is hovered (in this example, those divs are blue), to run an animation triggered by a class change.

Here is my code, but working only from top, then it doesn't go back to “normal”.

```
var header_links = document.getElementById("headerlinks"),
    blue_area = document.getElementsByClassName("blue_area");

// Detect on scroll
window.onscroll = function(e){
    if (e.pageY >= blue_area.offsetTop){
        header_links.classList.add("visible");
    }
    else {
        header_links.classList.remove("visible");
    }
};
```

(Not so working) JSFiddle here:
— https://jsfiddle.net/1bws8o3d/

Somehow [this plugin](https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check) detect brightness, but it is outdated and not very much what I'm looking for, but the idea is kinda the same.

Comment: It would be good to share a fiddle for this

Comment: @ardabeyazoglu: I edited my post with a jsfiddle but the JS doesn't work… but actually I'm just looking for detecting header links hovering blue areas, then add a class to a div for animating the logo

Comment: Does it need to be pure Javascript, or can you use JQuery?

Comment: @snookieordie: I try to avoid jQuery so if it can be vanilla that's cool!

Answer (score 2):

This may help you (It works on the fiddle):

Edit: Added firefox support.

```
var header_links = document.getElementById("headerlinks"),
blue_area = document.getElementsByClassName("blue_area")[0];

// Detect on scroll
window.onscroll = function(e){
  var startPos = ((e.pageY||document.body.scrollTop) + header_links.offsetHeight);
  var endPos = blue_area.offsetTop + blue_area.offsetHeight; 

  if(blue_area.offsetTop <= startPos && startPos <= endPos){
    header_links.classList.add("visible");
  }else{
    header_links.classList.remove("visible");
  }
};
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seems to work, even on the fiddle or on my local website. I got no "visible" class added when scrolling over blue areas

Comment: When i put these code to the js part of your fiddle and run, it works. I tried again, when i scroll over the blue area, the header goes red with "visible" css class.

Comment: Ha, you're right, but it works only in Chrome, I use Firefox so I didn't saw it. Otherwise, the logo doesn't goes back to blue when leaving a blue area, this is what I'm searching to achieve.

Comment: @flks i edited the code for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: @flks and i also made it going back to blue when leaving the blue area.

Answer (score 0):

My detection seems to be working with this condition! (hardly found… haha)

`if (e.pageY >= area.offsetTop - offset && e.pageY <= area.offsetTop + area.offsetHeight - 60){`

The full code:

```
var links = document.getElementById("headerlinks"),
    area = document.getElementById("blue_area"),
    offset = 150,
    logo = {
        animate: function(){ links.classList.add("over"); },
        stop: function(){ links.classList.remove("over"); }
    };

// Detect on scroll
// ON: If scroll position is after top of the area
// OFF: If scroll position is after end of the area
window.onscroll = function(e){
    if (e.pageY >= area.offsetTop - offset && e.pageY <= area.offsetTop + area.offsetHeight - 60){
        logo.animate();
    } else {
        logo.stop();
    }
};

// Detect on load
if ((window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) >= area.offsetTop - offset){
    logo.animate();
}
```